# Using Variable for Thread group Ramp up time

Tags: jmeter

how to configure the thread group ramp up time with a jmeter variable, I tried for both number of threads and ramp up time. No of threads is working fine, but ramp up time takes the default value 1 and the variable value doesn't take effect, Appreciate any help

Comment: Hi , any feedback on answer? thx

Answer (score 19):

You **cannot use variables in Thread Group setting** as Thread Groups are initialised during startup, before any variables are read.

If you need to make number of threads and/or ramp-up period configurable use [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) function like:

- `${__P(threads,)}`
- `${__P(rampup,)}`

[image: Properties]

Aforementioned `threads` and `rampup` properties can be defined in several ways:

1. If you run JMeter in [command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) you can pass the properties via -J command line key as

   ```
   jmeter -Jthreads=50 -Jrampup=30 -n -t /path/to/your/testplan.jmx
   ```

   The same approach will work for GUI mode, however it is not recommended to use GUI for load test execution as it is quite resource consuming and may ruin your test.
2. You can define these properties in *user.properties* file (located in /bin folder of your JMeter installation) as:

   ```
   threads=50
   rampup=30
   ```

   After restart JMeter will pick the properties up and you will be able to refer them via __P() function as described above.

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for comprehensive information on various JMeter properties and ways of working with them

Comment: JMeter is so easy to use, to pass an environment variable to it all you need to do is 1) set the environment variable 2) pass the environment variable to Jmeter with the -J commandline option 3) define a user-defined-variable that uses the obvious __p() function to read the variable 4) use that user defined varaible in youe step definition.  So much better than other apps that would do silly things like allow you to just set the OS env var and then refer to that in your step definition

Comment: There are better ways, for example [__env() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#envsupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup) like `${__env(your environment variable here,,)}` or [__groovy()](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) function like `${__groovy(System.getenv('your environment variable here'),)}`. At least JMeter is flexible enough to be used by such a highly skilled professional like you and a greenhorn like me and provides more than 1 way to implement this or that requirement

Comment: have to install a 3rd party plugin to read an environment variable lol.  And the groovy syntax is so concise.  But seriously thanks, that groovy method still far less clunky than the normal  -J and __P() way so i'm gonna switch to it.

Comment: Interestingly, even on Jmeter 5.2.1, I can use User Variables (based on Jmeter properties) for (1) number of threads and (2) test duration, but NOT for the ramp up period. Seems quite inconsistent.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason why it works for # of threads but doesn't work for ramp-up time. I've been using configurable properties for both with success.

1 is the default value in JMeter if variable can't be resolved properly. You likely made a typo. To investigate the problem, you may want to use 'Property Display' element (right-click WorkBench / Add / Non-Test Element / Property Display).

If this doesn't help, please post link to the screenshot of thread group, and relevant part of your config where you define the ramp-up time variable.

**EDIT : example**

This is the way I usually work with configurable properties stored in external files (and it works for ramp-up as well):

- define user defined variable on test plan level, e.g. someVarName is ${__P(someVarName)}
- then use this var e.g. in ramp-up as ${someVarName}

Comment: great thanks , WorkBench-Property Diaplay helped to find the mismatch in the variable name, Now it is working

Comment: If the answer helped you solving your problem, please consider voting up and/or accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use variables for those values, only properties:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html

> Properties are not the same as variables. Variables are local to a thread; properties are common to all threads, and need to be referenced using the __P or __property function.

Comment: You can use user defined variables defined on test plan level for those values.